# Delete accent from criteriaBuilder

Tags: java, hibernate-criteria

I am working on a criteria and I would like to remove the accents retrieved by a filter.

```
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.lower(root.get("gameTitle")), "%" + Normalizer.normalize(gameFilterDto.getFilter().toLowerCase(), Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll( [^\\p{ASCII}]", "") + "%"));
```

As for the filter, I use a Normalizer which works great. However, to do the same with the value of my Root <> is something else.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I get your question. What doesn't work and in what way?

Comment: @Thomas I get the value of root.get("gameTitle"). I would like this value to have no accent. But the normalizer does not work

Comment: Well, you'd probably need to call a "replace" function on the value if your database supports it (or you've rolled your own). I'm no criteria expert but have a look at `CriteriaBuilder.function()`.